# How can i remove plugin from this list in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to completely remove his plugin suggestion in my site this is showing in installed plugin list problem is that my client will try to install this and mess up with site and then blame me for not proper working of site so is there any way to remove this please help me.....[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TGM Plugin Activation](https://github.com/TGMPA/TGM-Plugin-Activation) is the most popular PHP library that most theme developers use to allow require or recommend plugins in their WordPress themes and plugins.

If your theme is also using the same library then you might need to modify the main theme files to remove those plugin suggestions or you might remove it using the child theme.

You might find this kind of line of code `add_action( 'tgmpa_register', 'mytheme_require_plugins' );` which you can remove from the child theme if it's not the case then you might need to modify the main theme files and remove the required code.

Check [this article](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-the-tgm-plugin-activation-library-in-your-themes--cms-20901) on how to use that library which will give an idea what to look on your main theme files and then you can find a way to remove it using child theme or by modifying the main theme files.